# Set interval in each request Node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, web-scraping

I have to make webscraping app but I read about that if will be a lot of request, then website can block my IP.

```
cn.query('SELECT url FROM models', function (err, row, field) {
    for (i in row) {
        request(row[i].url, (err, res, body) => {
            if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
                const $ = cheerio.load(body);
          //after getting data

            let sql = "INSERT INTO prodchar (year, Display, displaysize, os, Chipset, cpu, gpu, memoryslot, Storage, PrimaryCam, videocam, FrontCam, wlan, bluetooth, batdesc) VALUES ?";
                              // console.log(cn.query(sql, [arr]));
                              cn.query(sql, [[arr]], function(err, res) {
                                console.log(res);
                                if (err) throw err;
                                cn.query(
                                  "DELETE n1 FROM spec n1, spec n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.name = n2.name"
                                );
                              });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This is beginning of code. I have to take links from DB and in every iteration go into it and take the data. How can I set interval to every iteration row[i].url? For example set 2 minutes for every request. Please help ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try something with [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), like this ?

```
cn.query('SELECT url FROM models', function(err, rows, field) {

    let timeout = 2000; // 2 seconds

    let doRequest = (it, row) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            request(row.url, (err, res, body) => {
                if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
                    const $ = cheerio.load(body);
                }
            });
        }, it * timeout);
    };

    // Loop and call doRequest for each iteration
    for (let [it, row] of rows.entries()) {
        doRequest(it, row);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for answering. It works for interval but I dont know why, code take every single data 40 times. After request I write it to DB and in DB now I have each product that written 40 times.

Comment: Do it pass 40 times inside setTimeout function for each single row ?

Comment: Every single row goes to DB 40 times with different id(auto increment).

Comment: Humm.. it works fine for me.. Maybe your "cn.query" function in called 40 times ?

Comment: I dont think so. There is no such invoking. How can I show you all code? This is very important for me now. Help me please when you have time.

Comment: Can you show how you are pushing your data inside your database ?

Comment: let sql =
                                    "INSERT INTO prodchar (year, Display, displaysize, os, Chipset, cpu, gpu, memoryslot, Storage, PrimaryCam, videocam, FrontCam, wlan, bluetooth, batdesc) VALUES ?";
                                  
                                  cn.query(sql, [[arr]], function(err, res) {
                                    console.log(res);
                                    if (err) throw err;})
I have an array of products that I push to data.

Comment: It's ok for me, but I don't understand when / where this code is called ?

Comment: Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Sorry, It was a problem in my DB. Thank you for answer! You help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

use **async** library as below:

```
let interval = 5000;   
async.eachSeries(urlList, function (url, done) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        request(url, function(error, resp, body) { 
            if (error) return callback(error); 
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            done();
        });
    }, interval);
}, function (err) {
    if (!err) callback();
});
```